# What settings should my email server be mindful of to avoid bounce back from major email providers?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

So I think my postfix+dovecot+roundcube+postfixadmin+sasl+spamassassin+amavisd-new+postgrey setup is working correctly. I can send out emails to certain domain names. Receiving definitely works; however, when i send out emails to hotmail for instance I get a bounce back. Even worse yahoo doesn't even bounce it just kills the email all together.

I don't think I have been blacklisted or anything (maybe I have been? I don't even know.) so I am assuming that these companies don't like that some of my settings don't match up in my headers or something. Perhaps I have an IP or Server name instead of domain name somewhere or something. I am not sure.

Also is there a way to confirm that I have password protected SMTP? I am pretty sure it is; however, How can I be sure?

Here is the bounce back email:

> This is the mail system at host XXXXXXX.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
>   be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
>   delete your own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>                The mail system
> ```
>
> :
>       said: 550 OU-001 Mail rejected by Windows Live Hotmail for policy reasons.
>       Reasons for rejection may be related to content with spam-like
>       characteristics or IP/domain reputation problems. If you are not an
>       email/network admin please contact your E-mail/Internet Service Provider
>       for help. Email/network admins, please visit x for
>       email delivery information and support (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns; XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>   X-Postfix-Queue-ID: C9CD66C0F4
>   X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; XXXXXXXX
>   Arrival-Date: Sun,  4 Oct 2009 23:30:50 +0000 (UTC)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; XXXXX
>   Original-Recipient: rfc822;XXXXXX
>   Action: failed
>   Status: 5.0.0
>   Remote-MTA: dns; hotmailserver
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 OU-001 Mail rejected by Windows Live Hotmail for
>       policy reasons. Reasons for rejection may be related to content with
>       spam-like characteristics or IP/domain reputation problems. If you are not
>       an email/network admin please contact your E-mail/Internet Service Provider
>       for help. Email/network admins, please visit x for
>       email delivery information and support

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand the "question" but have you tried the tests here: http://www.mxtoolbox.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep, Windows Live can be a pain. Check:

- [You're not on a blacklist](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso)
- Your server has [MX and reverse DNS records](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/)
- You have [SPF DNS records](http://antone.geckotribe.com/alpha-gecko/how-to-set-up-spf-records/) (many servers reject mail without a valid SPF, GMail for example, here's [an explanation](http://www.ipswitch.com/support/ics/guides/IMailServer/8_2/IMailUGHTML/Chapter%202%20config12.html) and [a wizard](http://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx))
- Your mailserver's [HELO response matches your hostname](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/postfix-HELO.html)
- Your mailserver is [not an open relay](http://www.spamhelp.org/shopenrelay/)
- Your [DNS records' TTL](http://www.simpledns.com/help/v51/index.html?df_ttl.htm) is not too low - 86400 (24 hours) is recommended (some spammers set their TTL very low to regularly update forged DNS records)

Comment: I think that pretty well covers it. +1

Answer (score 0):

The MX record doesn't matter.  MX is purely for inbound.  Your SMTP server may not be the MX server.

The reverse DNS records have to exist, but they also have to match going both ways.
If you look up the IP, it produces a hostname.  If you look up the host name it must match the same IP, not a different IP, or it will be rejected.

Also, around the beginning of October, there was a problem with hotmail where they were rejecting all email from many cable company IPs.  I'd expect that problem is now past.

Comment: Agreed, it SHOULDN'T be an anti-spam criteria. However, you should at the very least receive postmaster@ email for any domain you send email from.